# IntelliJ Idea 10: how to turn off auto-complete in .txt files

Tags: intellij-idea, code-completion

I've just upgraded to IntelliJ IDEA 10, and it has started doing something extremely annoying. While writing documentation in a .txt file it has started giving me word suggestions as I type. This is, instead of helping, just irritating me while also consuming system resources. I haven't been able to find a way to turn this off in the Settings window. Perhaps there's a way of telling Idea not to do this for certain file types or in code comments?

Answer (score 12):

Goto

```
Settings/Preferences -> General -> Editor -> Code Completion
```

and untick `Show the parameter info popup` to something like `1000` (ms), then it give you time to carry on typing before the pop up.

Or disable settings such as `Show suggestions as you type`

Comment: That affects all files, not just text files.

Answer (score 8):

For intelliJ 2016.2.2, it defaults to auto insert code suggestions which is very annoying. Even when typing space, it overrides what I'm typing and puts something random in. Here's the solution:

1. Go to **Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion**
2. Then, UNCHECK the box that says "Insert selected variant by typing dot, space, etc." See screenshot below

[image: See this]

Comment: Is there a way to set up a shortcut key/hotkey for this setting?

Answer (score 5):

You are not alone, please watch/vote for [IDEABKL-5963](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEABKL-5963).

Comment: Ah, good to know I'm not the only one.  I've had to resort to turning off all code completion when writing documentation files :)  Cheers, R

Comment: It really seems odd there's so little activity on this issue.