# Why is IntelliJ using autocomplete in a plain text file and how do I turn it off?

Tags: autocomplete, intellij-idea, ini

In trying to edit a 2300+ line .ini file Intellij is *really* slow, as in 1-2 seconds after keystroke before the letter appears. I see autocomplete popping up and I assume that's why its slow, but its a plain text file, why is it even giving me autocomplete?

And ok, its only registered as plain text because I haven't figured out how to get it to support hierarchical config files nicely, and autocomplete could be useful here, but it shouldn't be that slow.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985663/intellij-idea-10-how-to-turn-off-auto-complete-in-txt-files

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried clicking the police icon in the right lower corner? Setting the "Highlighting Level" to None it speeds up most things when working with large files of any kind.