# Disable Intellij IDEA append space after code autocomplete

Tags: java, intellij-idea

An example: When I want to type `public`, I type `pub` and press <kbd>tab</kbd>, IDEA automatically append a <kbd>space</kbd> after `public`, how can I turn off it.

Because I am used to tapping <kbd>space</kbd> after autocompletion, so every time after that, there are 2 spaces and I have to delete one. Other IDEs or text editors I've used seem not to append that <kbd>space</kbd> automatically.

Comment: why would you want to turn that off?

Comment: [How to turn off autocomplete in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985663/intellij-idea-10-how-to-turn-off-auto-complete-in-txt-files)

Comment: @kaan Because I am used to tapping space after autocompletion, so every time after that, there are 2 spaces and I have to delete one. Other IDEs or text editors I've used seem not to append that space automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable this particular piece of autocomplete behavior in IDEA short of disabling autocompletion feature altogether.

You can, however, use the 'Reformat' action to apply single default format to your whole file (`Ctrl+Alt+L`) or 'Complete Current Statement' action after you are done typing a construct (highlight the statement and press `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`). Conformed to the default formatting settings, double spaces should be replaced with single ones.

---

Assuming that this is for Java code (although the general mechanism is true for most file types), you can modify when/how spaces are used in code.

Go to **File | Settings | Code Style | Java**.

If you then click on the Spaces tab you can specify the code layout you want. After you've done this if you reformat your code it should format according to your preferences.

You can specify this for other types too (General, CSS, JavaScript and so on).